# FB Share Button with custom text

Tags: facebook

We use the facebook share button in a part of our website. We used to be able to change the text of the button but it seems to be no longer possible.

The code we have right now is:

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="http://<?=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]?><?=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]?>"></a>
```

We need to modify the Button so say "Share this product" instead of just share.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

The Share button is deprecated, instead you should use the Feed Dialog along with your own custom design of button. Here is an example:

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation&description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response">Share this product</a>`

Which appears as:

[Share this product](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation&description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response)

As you can see, it's really easy to create and is actually supported, so I highly recommend switching.