# Styling social sharing buttons

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, twitter, google-plus

By referring Social sharing button api's such as Facebook, twitter and google plus, I created a simple fiddle to share a link (example: `http://www.google.com`).

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/UL6XB/2/)

My fiddle is working fine but the links specifically twitters is coming with a default style which I don't want to have.

I was actually planning to have non-styled plain text as social sharing buttons.

I tried to change the styling or trigger the sharing buttons with alternate anchor elements but realised that it is not possible because the sharing button links are generating in IFRAME.

Any help on how to change the stylings of these buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with the data-attributes passed in the twitter link. Like

http://jsfiddle.net/UL6XB/6/

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="" data-url="http://www.google.com" data-via="your_screen_name" data-text="Checking out this page about Tweet Buttons" data-count="none">
```

Comment: Thanks for response... BUT.. If I click twitter, then the new page is opening in the same page. I am not willing to change the default functionality but just default styling..

Comment: Add attribute target="_blank" to the twitter "a" tag

Comment: that is not the only issue here.. the data-attributes passing to the twitter share link are not being passed to the new window/tab.

Comment: better option is to use intent/tweet instead of /share. updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UL6XB/8/
this opens up a separate window instead of a tab.

Comment: Thanks.. I am trying here :)

Comment: Yes, working fine.. anyway to do the same with facebook? I mean now the text is coming like `share on Facebook` but I just want to show `Facebook`.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636122/fb-share-button-with-custom-text for this. And if the answer solved your problem please accept it as correct answer, which might be an indicator for other users also.

Answer (score 2):

So these sites have specific rules about what you are and aren't allowed to do with their branding for elements such as sharing links, buttons with logos, etc.

https://www.facebookbrand.com/

https://about.twitter.com/press/brand-assets

https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines

That being said, your issue is that you're pulling in the `twitter-share-button` class, which is mutating the element into a button.  Get rid of that and you'll just see text.